# What is the slowest running speed?

Tags: team-fortress-2

As somewhat similar to the Fastest Running Speed question, I'm curious what the slowest running speed possible would be.

I've been thinking a Soldier at crouching speed, moving backwards, while getting pelted by bullets from a Natascha.

Is there something slower than this?

Comment: Are controllers allowed?

Comment: @badp Do controllers limit the speed in some way?

Comment: Yes. Movement input is on the left analogue stick, and if you don't pull the stick in one direction all the way, the character will go slower than normal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically if you are all of the following, you cannot move at all.

- A Heavy
- With the Brass Beast
- Spun Up
- Crouching

However, **every** class is capable of not moving, and any class that is hit by a full-range Sandman ball immediately stops moving.  So this is not a unique feature of a spun-up Brass Beast heavy (though they are by far, without crouching or any status effects, the slowest class in the game).

Next to that in terms of non-crouch speed would probably be a Baby Face's Blaster Scout without any boost, followed by a Soldier's ground speed, followed by an Engie hauling a building, followed by a Demoman.

Answer (score -1):

Yes there is something slower as a matter of fact. The same thing as a HEAVY while spinning his mini gun.